# check if point exists in QPainterPath

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt

I have an application where I place several curves in my scene. I was looking for an easy way to detect if the user pressed on the line. `boundingRect()` and `intersects()` were too inaccurate when I was having multiple lines drawn. So I made this function, which works like a dream except when the lines are vertical.

`selectionMargin` is a global variable set by the user (default = 0.5). It adjusts the margin for how accurate the selection check should be. Names are based on the linear function for each subline, `y = ax + b`. Pos is the position from the mousePressEvent.

```
bool GraphApp::pointInPath(QPainterPath path, QPointF pos)
{
    qreal posY = pos.y();
    qreal posX = pos.x();

    for (int i = 0; i < path.elementCount()-1; ++i) {
        if (posX < path.elementAt(i + 1).x && posX > path.elementAt(i).x) {
            qreal dy = path.elementAt(i + 1).y - path.elementAt(i).y;
            qreal dx = path.elementAt(i + 1).x - path.elementAt(i).x;
            qreal a = dy / dx;
            qreal b = path.elementAt(i).y - (path.elementAt(i).x * a);

            if (selectionMargin == 0.0)
                selectionMargin = 0.5;

            qreal lowerBound = (a * posX + b) + selectionMargin;
            qreal upperBound = (a * posX + b) - selectionMargin;

            if (posY < lowerBound && posY > upperBound)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So it seems like this function returns false when I send a mousePressEvent from the area coverd by the vertical lines. My first thought is the if-sentence:

```
if (posX < path.elementAt(i + 1).x && posX > path.elementAt(i).x)
```

Any other ideas for how I can implement this without the if-sentence?

I have also seen other people struggling with finding a nice way to check if a `QPainterPath` contains a point without the `boundingRect()` and `intersects()` functions, so this is maybe to use for other people as well :)

EDIT: As far as I know, `contains()` uses `boundingRect()`. So I would not see that as a proper solution

Comment: What if you created a small rectangle around your point (+/- your Margin) and use 'intersects' on your Path and Rect?

Comment: Yep, seems like a good approach, but for me it seems like intersects() then checks if the small rectangle intersects with the bounding rectangle of the path. That could be difficult when the path drawn is a straight horizontal line. Let's say the path is a sinus curve. Then the bounding rectangle would be really huge and making a possible selection area too big.

Comment: The problem is: `intersects` and `contains` test for filled paths, not the "line".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I once needed something similar than you. I needed to test two paths for similarity. Therefore I created a path from a list of points (I hope you don't need a more complex path since this solution would become extremely more difficult for general QPaintingPaths). This path is constructed using a given "tolerance", this is your `selectionMargin`.

The function returns a QPainterPath which "draws a region around the given polyline". This region can then be filled and would result in the same image as drawing the original polyline using a pen width of `tolerance` using round cap and round join options.

You can also, and this is what you want to do, check if a given point is contained in this path. Note that `QPainterPath::contains` checks for a point to lie within the closed region defined by the path. E.g., this closed region is empty for a single line segment and a triangle for two line segments, so this is not what you want if you use `contains` directly on your path (as I mentioned in the 3rd comment to your question).

```
QPainterPath intersectionTestPath(QList<QPointF> input, qreal tolerance)
{
    //will be the result
    QPainterPath path;

    //during the loop, p1 is the "previous" point, initially the first one
    QPointF p1 = input.takeFirst(); 

    //begin with a circle around the start point
    path.addEllipse(p1, tolerance, tolerance); 

    //input now starts with the 2nd point (there was a takeFirst)
    foreach(QPointF p2, input) 
    {
        //note: during the algorithm, the pair of points (p1, p2)
        //      describes the line segments defined by input.

        //offset = the distance vector from p1 to p2
        QPointF offset = p2 - p1;

        //normalize offset to length of tolerance
        qreal length = sqrt(offset.x() * offset.x() + offset.y() * offset.y());
        offset *= tolerance / length;

        //"rotate" the offset vector 90 degrees to the left and right
        QPointF leftOffset(-offset.y(), offset.x());
        QPointF rightOffset(offset.y(), -offset.x());

        //if (p1, p2) goes downwards, then left lies to the left and
        //right to the right of the source path segment
        QPointF left1 = p1 + leftOffset; 
        QPointF left2 = p2 + leftOffset;
        QPointF right1 = p1 + rightOffset;
        QPointF right2 = p2 + rightOffset;

        //rectangular connection from p1 to p2
        {
            QPainterPath p;
            p.moveTo(left1);
            p.lineTo(left2);
            p.lineTo(right2);
            p.lineTo(right1);
            p.lineTo(left1);
            path += p; //add this to the result path
        }

        //circle around p2
        {
            QPainterPath p;
            p.addEllipse(p2, tolerance, tolerance);
            path += p; //add this to the result path
        }

        p1 = p2;
    }

    //This does some simplification; you should use this if you call
    //path.contains() multiple times on a pre-calculated path, but
    //you won't need this if you construct a new path for every call
    //to path.contains().
    return path.simplified();
}
```